# Spring-Data (JPA) with EJB3(javax) without Springframework JBOSS AS7

Tags: ejb-3.0, spring-data

Following situation. I want to use spring-data because I like the Domain JpaRepository(interface) system.

Here comes the BUT, i dont want to use the Spring-Framework itself. I'd like to stick to the javax.* ejb3 specification

I am trying to set up a project configuration.

I have a project with the spring-data-jpa which represents the pesristance layer. I am using  @Stateless instead of springs @Service and @Inject instead of @autowired (since i heard there synonyms. Accountservice inside the persistancelayer is only there for testing purporses.

```
PersistanceModule(Eclipseproject)
|
|-com.ns.persistance
|   |-domain
|       |-Account
|   |-repository
|       |-AccountRepository (JpaRepositry interface)
|   |-test
|       |-AccountService (which contains a method do save a user in the database)
```

AccountRepository

```
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> { 

    Account findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Account Service for testing purposes.

```
@Stateless
public class AccountService {

    @Inject
    private AccountRepository ar;

    public void createTestAccount() {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setUsername("testAccount");
        account.setPassword("sicheres passwort");
        account.setEmail("kks.cs@web.de");
        account.setCreationTime(new Date());
        account.setLastModificationDate(new Date());

        account = ar.save(account);

    }
}
```

Workjob to test spring data

```
@Singleton
public class SSService {

    @EJB
    AccountService as;

    @Schedule(minute = "*/5", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void doWork() {

        System.out.println("WorkJob!!!!!!!");
        //as.createTestAccount();

    }

}
```

I have a spring-data-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.ns.persistence.repository" />

</beans>
```

JBoss keeps telling me AccountService is NULL (Nullpointer). I believe i forgot to set up some configuration, but i cant get the hang of it and googling keeps getting me simple Springframework solutions.
My Question:
What did i miss?
Does spring data work with EJB(javax) or do i need to use the springframework.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure you get this right. To use Spring Data JPA you will need to use the Spring framework. You don't need to use the container necessarily (XML configuration, container setup) but you will need the Spring JARs on your applications class path.

As of version 1.1.0.RC1 (already released) the Spring Data JPA project supports being run inside an CDI container which JBoss AS7 is one instance of. So with Spring Data JPA of the juste mentioned version in place this should be working. The Spring configuration file is not needed then, only an empty `beans.xml` as specified by CDI.

If you're using an earlier version you'll have to write some code to instantiate the repository instances yourself:

```
 @Stateless
 class YourService {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   private AccountRepository repository

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
      RepositoryFactorySupport factory = new JpaRepositoryFactory(em);
      this.repository = factory.getRepository(AccountRepository.class);
   }
}
```

It might make sense to have that code into a common component and let that instance be injected into services then to avoid to rewrite this setup code in every service implementation. As I mentioned above: as of the upcoming 1.1.0 versions this will be working out of the box.